# How to connect non-sharepoint site to create items in SharePoint (both on same machine)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, sharepoint-server, rest

Scenario:

- I've created a custom list 'TestList' in SharePoint
- On this same server, I created a simple (non-SharePoint) website in pure HTML

Please how can I connect the form on this (non-SharePoint) website to programmatically create items in SharePoint using **JSOM/REST API**

I am not able to use SharePoint Apps because it is not configured on machine likewise a major requirement was for the HTML website NOT to inherit or resemble any of SharePoint UI such that the user never knows they are interacting with SharePoint behind-the-scenes.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom REST Service which can call SP and you can use the REST API for all CRUD operations:

You can follow this article to help create the REST Service:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call

Here is a tutorial on how to use REST API on SharePoint:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If there is no restriction on .Net based solutions, you can host a .Net site on the same server instead of the HTML site.

This would give you access to the server side libraries which can easily do operations on SharePoint. You can have any UI you want and also have the user restrictions in place by having IIS impersonate the requestor.

Cross domain calls to SharePoint APIs can be tricky to achieve from an html application, your solution will have much lesser code and complexity by using the SharePoint dlls.